# summarizing a tab separated file in pandas

Tags: python

I have big `tab separated` file like this:

`small example`:

```
CHTOP   237 122
CHTOP   64  53
CHTOP   64  122
RPS27   986 66
RPS27   986 50
RPS27   986 227
```

I want to group the rows according to the 1st column and sum all numbers in the 2nd column which belong the same group and do the same for the numbers in the 3rd column. for instance for the small example we have 2 groups
the expected output would be:

`expected output`:

```
CHTOP   365 297
RPS27   2958    343
```

I used pandas in python but it does not return 3 columns file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt',sep=None)
df = df.groupby(['ID']).cumcount()
df.to_csv('result.txt', sep='\t', index=None)
```

do you know how to fix it?

Comment: user10657934, could you please provide a feedback on my answer and either accept it or explain why it is not satisfactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several observations:

1. Since there is no header row in `myfile.txt`, we need to tell it to `pandas`, otherwise the first row will be treated as the header.
2. Since the columns are unnamed, there is no such thing as the `'ID'` column. To group rows by the ID, use the number of the column (0) instead.
3. To sum the rows belonging to the same group, use `sum()`, not `cumcount()`.

Also, it is better to explicitly state that `myfile.txt` is tab (not comma) separated because the C engine is unable to detect the separator automatically.

Here is a proposed solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', sep='\t', header=None)
df = df.groupby(0).sum()
df.to_csv('result.txt', sep='\t', header=None)
```